# Transição de imagem css e html

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, layout-responsivo

Galera, estou começando a me interessar por html e css, tenho estudado e fiz um curso, e estou fazendo esse site. Coloquei uma transição para quando ele rolar a barra lateral, mas queria que ficasse mais suave a transição com imagem, com o texto usei o transicion 1s no próprio css, mas pra imagem não funciona

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y < 25) {
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'padding-bottom': '10px'
    });
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'height': '68px'
    });
    $('.im').css({
      'padding': '10px 10px 22px 10px'
    });
    $('.icon').css({
      'display': 'inline-block'
    });
    $('.efc').css({
      'display': 'initial'
    });
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'transition': '0.2s'
    });
  } else {
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'padding': '0px'
    });
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'margin': '0px'
    });
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'height': '40px'
    });
    $('.im').css({
      'padding': '20px 10px 2px 10px'
    });
    $('.icon').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    $('.efc').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'transition': '0.3s'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
  font-family: Agency FB;
  src: url(../_fontes/agencyfb.ttf);
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/*Corpo do site*/

.postagem {
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, .05);
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
}


/*Divisão de conteudo do meu site*/

#interface {
  width: 1100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}


/*Cabeçalho do meu site*/

.cabecalho {
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 68px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, 1);
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: 'Agency FB';
  font-size: 20pt;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fcor {
  color: rgba(255, 220, 180, 1);
}


/*Menu*/

.menu {
  display: block;
}

.mn {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon {}

.mn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.im {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10pt;
  transition: 0s;
  font-family: 'Agency FB';
  padding: 10px 10px 22px 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.efc {}

.im:hover {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: rgba(244, 116, 0, 1);
}


/*Postagens*/

.artigo {
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: justify;
}

.li {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
  font-style: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.icone {
  transition: 2s;
  border: solid white 6px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
}


/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/

.tabela {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tdn {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.vazio {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.vazio#vm {
  padding: 36px;
}

.tabt {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.subt {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.ft {
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.asst {
  padding: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="../_imagens/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../_imagens/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Checklist, manutenção de computador</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_css/estilo.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">

    <nav class="menu">
      <h1 hidden>Menu Principal</h1>
      <ul class="mn">
        <a href="../index.html">
          <li class="im"><img class="icon" src="../_imagens/icasa.png"><br class="efc">Home</li>
          <a href="../index.html">
            <li class="im"><img class="icon" src="../_imagens/ilivro.png"><br class="efc">Manuais e Processos</li>
          </a>
          <a href="../index.html">
            <li class="im"><img class="icon" src="../_imagens/iferramentas.png"><br class="efc">Equipamentos</li>
          </a>
          <a href="../index.html">
            <li class="im"><img class="icon" src="../_imagens/ietiqueta.png"><br class="efc">Inventário</li>
          </a>
          <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA</span></h1>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="interface">
    <article class="artigo">
      <h1 class="titulo">CHECKLIST, MANUTENÇÃO DE COMPUTADOR</h1>
      <p class="paragrafo">
        <table class="tabela" style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th class="tabt" colspan="4">CHECKLIST DE MANUTENÇÃO DE COMPUTADOR</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt">OS</th>
            <th class="subt">NOME DA MÁQUINA</th>
            <th class="subt">USUÁRIO</th>
            <th class="subt">SETOR</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="vazio"> </td>
            <td class="vazio"> </td>
            <td class="vazio"> </td>
            <td class="vazio"> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">MANUTENÇÃO FÍSICA</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="3">PASSO A PASSO</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Limpeza física interna</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Limpeza física externa</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">VERIFICAÇÃO INICIAL</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="3">PASSO A PASSO</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Efetuar backup</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Executar diagnóstico do Dell/Lenovo</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Remoção de todos os bloatware</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">STATUS DO EQUIPAMENTO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">NOME DO HARDWARE</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">CAPACIDADE</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">STATUS DO HARDWARE</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="1">Memória RAM</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="1">Disco Rigido</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">INSTALAÇÃO BÁSICA</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="3">PASSO A PASSO</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3"><a href="1009181.html" class="link">Instalar sistema operacional</a></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3"><a href="1009183.html" class="link">Alterar nome do computador</a></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3"><a href="1009184.html" class="link">Inserir máquina no domínio usinacoruripe.com.br</a></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Verificar chave de licença do sistema operacional</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Adicionar gg_Informatica no grupo Administradores local</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Ativar acesso remoto de área de trabalho (Com permissão p/ gg_Informatica)</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Oracle</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Centura (Gupta)</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Criar atalho do Gestão Coruripe na área de trabalho publica</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar SAP Gui</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Adobe Acrobat Reader DC</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar UltraVNC Server</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar 7Zip</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Citrix Receiver</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Mozilla Firefox</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Google Chrome</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Diminuir o level UAC</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Agent OCS (Executar como Administrador)</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Antivirus Symantec</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Verificar atualizações disponiveis no Windows Update</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Verificar atualizações de drivers no computador</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">INSTALAÇÃO DE SOFTWARE CONDICIONAIS</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="3">NOME</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Microsoft Office</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Skype for Business</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Java</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">CutePDF</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">DESCRIÇÃO DO RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="vazio" id="vm" colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="ft">
            <td class="asst" colspan="2">CONFERIDO POR:_________________</td>
            <td class="asst" colspan="2">ANALISTA RESPONSÁVEL:_________________________</td>

          </tr>
        </table>
      </p>
      <article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Queria também centralizar esse meu logo, fiz ele usando inline-block, queria centralizar apenas o logo e deixar o menu a esquerda.

Answer (score 2):

Para dar um aspecto mais fluído, já que está realizando tudo via JQuery... ao invés de setar `display:none` para a `.icon` você pode utilizar o os métodos de `fade()`.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y < 25) {
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'padding-bottom': '10px'
    });
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'height': '68px'
    });
    $('.im').css({
      'padding': '10px 10px 22px 10px'
    });

    $('.efc').css({
      'display': 'initial'
    });
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'transition': '0.2s'
    });
    $('.icon').fadeIn();

  } else {

    $('.icon').fadeOut(200, function() {

      $('.cabecalho').css({
        'padding': '0px'
      });
      $('.cabecalho').css({
        'margin': '0px'
      });
      $('.cabecalho').css({
        'height': '40px'
      });
      $('.im').css({
        'padding': '20px 10px 2px 10px'
      });

      $('.efc').css({
        'display': 'none'
      });

      $('.cabecalho').css({
        'transition': '0.3s'
      });

    });
  }
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
  font-family: Agency FB;
  src: url(../_fontes/agencyfb.ttf);
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/*Corpo do site*/

.postagem {
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, .05);
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
}


/*Divisão de conteudo do meu site*/

#interface {
  width: 1100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}


/*Cabeçalho do meu site*/

.cabecalho {
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 68px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, 1);
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: 'Agency FB';
  font-size: 20pt;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fcor {
  color: rgba(255, 220, 180, 1);
}


/*Menu*/

.menu {
  display: block;
}

.mn {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon {}

.mn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.im {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10pt;
  transition: 0s;
  font-family: 'Agency FB';
  padding: 10px 10px 22px 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.efc {}

.im:hover {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: rgba(244, 116, 0, 1);
}


/*Postagens*/

.artigo {
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: justify;
}

.li {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
  font-style: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.icone {
  transition: 2s;
  border: solid white 6px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
}


/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/

.tabela {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tdn {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.vazio {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.vazio#vm {
  padding: 36px;
}

.tabt {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.subt {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.ft {
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.asst {
  padding: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="../_imagens/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../_imagens/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Checklist, manutenção de computador</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_css/estilo.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">

    <nav class="menu">
      <h1 hidden>Menu Principal</h1>
      <ul class="mn">
        <a href="../index.html">
          <li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32x32-free-design-icons/32/Home.png"><br class="efc">Home</li>
          <a href="../index.html">
            <li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32x32-free-design-icons/32/Help_book.png"><br class="efc">Manuais e Processos</li>
          </a>
          <a href="../index.html">
            <li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32x32-free-design-icons/32/Tools.png"><br class="efc">Equipamentos</li>
          </a>
          <a href="../index.html">
            <li class="im"><img class="icon" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32x32-free-design-icons/32/List.png"><br class="efc">Inventário</li>
          </a>
          <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA</span></h1>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="interface">
    <article class="artigo">
      <h1 class="titulo">CHECKLIST, MANUTENÇÃO DE COMPUTADOR</h1>
      <p class="paragrafo">
        <table class="tabela" style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th class="tabt" colspan="4">CHECKLIST DE MANUTENÇÃO DE COMPUTADOR</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt">OS</th>
            <th class="subt">NOME DA MÁQUINA</th>
            <th class="subt">USUÁRIO</th>
            <th class="subt">SETOR</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="vazio"> </td>
            <td class="vazio"> </td>
            <td class="vazio"> </td>
            <td class="vazio"> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">MANUTENÇÃO FÍSICA</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="3">PASSO A PASSO</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Limpeza física interna</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Limpeza física externa</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">VERIFICAÇÃO INICIAL</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="3">PASSO A PASSO</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Efetuar backup</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Executar diagnóstico do Dell/Lenovo</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Remoção de todos os bloatware</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">STATUS DO EQUIPAMENTO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">NOME DO HARDWARE</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">CAPACIDADE</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">STATUS DO HARDWARE</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="1">Memória RAM</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="1">Disco Rigido</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">INSTALAÇÃO BÁSICA</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="3">PASSO A PASSO</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3"><a href="1009181.html" class="link">Instalar sistema operacional</a></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3"><a href="1009183.html" class="link">Alterar nome do computador</a></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3"><a href="1009184.html" class="link">Inserir máquina no domínio usinacoruripe.com.br</a></td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Verificar chave de licença do sistema operacional</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Adicionar gg_Informatica no grupo Administradores local</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Ativar acesso remoto de área de trabalho (Com permissão p/ gg_Informatica)</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Oracle</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Centura (Gupta)</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Criar atalho do Gestão Coruripe na área de trabalho publica</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar SAP Gui</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Adobe Acrobat Reader DC</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar UltraVNC Server</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar 7Zip</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Citrix Receiver</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Mozilla Firefox</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Google Chrome</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Diminuir o level UAC</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Agent OCS (Executar como Administrador)</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Instalar Antivirus Symantec</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Verificar atualizações disponiveis no Windows Update</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Verificar atualizações de drivers no computador</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">INSTALAÇÃO DE SOFTWARE CONDICIONAIS</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="3">NOME</th>
            <th class="subt" colspan="1">RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Microsoft Office</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Skype for Business</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">Java</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdn" colspan="3">CutePDF</td>
            <td class="vazio" colspan="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="subt" colspan="4">DESCRIÇÃO DO RESULTADO</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="vazio" id="vm" colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="ft">
            <td class="asst" colspan="2">CONFERIDO POR:_________________</td>
            <td class="asst" colspan="2">ANALISTA RESPONSÁVEL:_________________________</td>

          </tr>
        </table>
      </p>
      <article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```